# How to select what button is being clicked on a multi-button click event, backed by sql

Tags: sql, vb.net, forms, button

I am currently working in VB.net express 2013, using windows form applications. I have a panel with 84 buttons on it and each button represents a physical cell. When the button is pressed I have a dialog result that pops up to show the contents of that cell. However, I don't know how to make the code pull the name of that button and throw it into the sql statement for the where portion. My buttons are design named cmdM01, cmdM02, 
cmdM03....etc. etc. The sql names are M01, M02, M03, etc. etc. 
*Note, i am using 1 = @shear for testing for now. I need to figure out how to replace that "1" for something that will identify the cell.
Here is my code so far:

```
   Public Sub Button_Click(ByVal o As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles cmdM01.Click, cmdM02.Click, cmdM03.Click, cmdM04.Click, cmdM05.Click, cmdM06.Click, cmdM07.Click,
    cmdM08.Click, cmdM09.Click, cmdM10.Click, cmdM11.Click, cmdM12.Click, cmdT01.Click, cmdT02.Click, cmdT03.Click, cmdT04.Click, cmdT05.Click, cmdT06.Click, cmdT07.Click, cmdT08.Click,
    cmdT09.Click, cmdT10.Click, cmdT11.Click, cmdT12.Click, cmdT13.Click, cmdT14.Click, cmdT15.Click, cmdT16.Click, cmdT17.Click, cmdT18.Click, cmdT19.Click, cmdT20.Click,
    cmdT21.Click, cmdT22.Click, cmdT23.Click, cmdT24.Click, cmdH01.Click, cmdH02.Click, cmdH03.Click, cmdH04.Click, cmdH05.Click, cmdH06.Click, cmdH07.Click, cmdH08.Click, cmdH09.Click,
    cmdH10.Click, cmdH11.Click, cmdH12.Click, cmdH13.Click, cmdH14.Click, cmdH15.Click, cmdH16.Click, cmdH17.Click, cmdH18.Click, cmdH19.Click, cmdH20.Click, cmdH21.Click,
    cmdH22.Click, cmdH23.Click, cmdH24.Click, cmdP01.Click, cmdP02.Click, cmdP03.Click, cmdP04.Click, cmdP05.Click, cmdP06.Click, cmdP07.Click, cmdP08.Click, cmdP09.Click, cmdP10.Click,
    cmdP11.Click, cmdP12.Click, cmdP13.Click, cmdP14.Click, cmdP15.Click, cmdP16.Click, cmdP17.Click, cmdP18.Click, cmdP19.Click, cmdP20.Click, cmdP21.Click, cmdP22.Click, cmdP23.Click, cmdP24.Click

    'load selection for all buttons

    Using conn1 As New SqlConnection(connstring)
        conn1.Open()
        Using comm1 As New SqlCommand("SELECT Shear FROM Production.dbo.tblFabWipLog WHERE FabWipID = @Cell", conn1)
            comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cell", 1)
            Dim sql As New SqlDataAdapter(comm1)
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            sql.Fill(dt)
            Dim f As New CellContent
            f.LabelShear.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Shear").ToString
            f.ShowDialog()
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I determine which button was clicked, and then use a `Select Case` to determine what to do with said button click.

```
Dim bt As Button = o
Dim btName As String = bt.Text
```

In your case if the name of the button or the id is tied directly to a value you can just pass that into your parameters by accessing it from the bt variable.

Comment: Genius, I can figure out the select case example on my own. You are awesome man.

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this

```
Dim btnName as string = o.name
```

to determine which button was clicked